# Spring JPA long wait time

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple DAL using Spring-boot/security/jpa on MSSQL backend. This is working great apart from some calls take an age to return.
Reviewing the logs, I can see that some JPA methods are idle for ages (23>sec). Note that the code is doing nothing at this point as it's all Spring JPA and not "real code".
The calls to the database and OAuth take around 30ms and the rest is what??

The data returned is around 100 records with less than 5 properties so the data requirement is relatively small.

It can't take 23> seconds to serialize some POJO?
I'm not sure how to hunt this down as it's not my code, but part of the Spring Framework.
Any advice would be gratefully appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Spring won't be the issue.  Your best bet is to profile the code and see where the time is being spent.  Take a look with Visual VM>. You don't say what your connection pool configuration looks like and other useful details.  That might be useful to know.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx to @duffymo for the helping hand.

This was down to logs. We have Trace set and this was causing issues with non-synchronous logging.

Turn off logs: 30ms
Turn on TRACE: 30 s